# How would I edit a TextView outside of onCreate if it must be declared inside onCreate?

Tags: java, android

I've run into a problem where trying to call `TextView` for dollars inside `onTap` makes the app crash. Moving it to `onCreate()` works however then I cannot set the text from inside of `onTap()`. How would I make it so I can put the textview inside of `onTap` or make it so I can access the textview outside of `oncreate`?

```
package com.de_veloper.idlegame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    TextView dollars;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dollars = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dollars);
    }

    //
    //
    //
    //code beginning
    //
    //
    //
    public int do_llars;
    public int upg_click_cost;
    public int upg_click_effect;
    public int upg_click_level;

    String $do_llars = String.valueOf(do_llars);
    String $upg_click_cost = String.valueOf(upg_click_cost);
    String $upg_click_level = String.valueOf(upg_click_level);
    String $upg_click_effect = String.valueOf(upg_click_effect);


    public void onTap(View view){
        if (upg_click_level == 0){
            upg_click_level = 1;
            upg_click_effect = 1;
            upg_click_effect = upg_click_level * upg_click_effect;
        }
        do_llars = do_llars + upg_click_effect;
        dollars.setText($do_llars);

    }

    public void upgradeBuy(){


    }

}
```

XML Code is here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/moneybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16pt"
        android:padding="50px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onTap"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/totaldo_llars"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Total do_llars: "
        android:textSize="8pt" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/do_llars"
        android:id="@+id/dollars"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/totaldo_llars"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/totaldo_llars"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/totaldo_llars"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its the first textview dude

Comment: does that textview need an ID? that textview is never going to be modified. it simply is there to execute onTap

Comment: There is posibility that you are not getting any value in "$do_llars" .So,Just hard code the value of "$do_llars" for testing and check is value changed on click or not.... As code look fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seem to be in variables. You are setting up your String variables $do_llars, $upg_click_cost, $upg_click_level, $upg_click_effect well before assigning any values to do_llars, upg_click_cost, upg_click_effect, upg_click_level. So modify you code as

```
public int do_llars;
public int upg_click_cost;
public int upg_click_effect;
public int upg_click_level;

String $do_llars = ""; //String.valueOf(do_llars);
String $upg_click_cost = ""; //String.valueOf(upg_click_cost);
String $upg_click_level = ""; //String.valueOf(upg_click_level);
String $upg_click_effect = ""; //String.valueOf(upg_click_effect);

public void onTap(View view){
    if (upg_click_level == 0){
        upg_click_level = 1;
        $upg_click_level = String.valueOf(upg_click_level);
        upg_click_effect = 1;
        upg_click_effect = upg_click_level * upg_click_effect;
        $upg_click_effect = String.valueOf(upg_click_effect);
    }
    do_llars = do_llars + upg_click_effect;
    $do_llars = String.valueOf(do_llars);
    dollars.setText($do_llars);
}
```

When you assign value to `upg_click_cost` you can initialize `$upg_click_cost` in same way. 
But instead of maintaining int and string variables separately i would suggest where ever you wish to display the value of `do_llars, upg_click_cost, upg_click_effect, upg_click_level` use `String.valueOf(do_llars), String.valueOf(upg_click_cost), String.valueOf(upg_click_effect), String.valueOf(upg_click_level)` so that you do not require to assign the updated value to String variable each time you change int variables.

Answer (score 0):

change
       dollars.setText($do_llars); to
       view..setText($do_llars);

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
String $do_llars = String.valueOf(do_llars);
```

is executed before `do_llars` is assigned any value and maybe that is causing null reference exception.

Solution: Either call the above statement after assigning do_llars a valuue or try [Syed Zainul Abedin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32153088/3286583)'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. This is my code now

```
package com.de_veloper.idlegame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    TextView dollars;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dollars = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dollars);
    }

    //
    //
    //
    //code beginning
    //
    //
    //
    public int do_llars;
    public int upg_click_cost;
    public int upg_click_effect;
    public int upg_click_level;





    public void onTap(View view){
        //da strings
        String $do_llars = String.valueOf(do_llars);
        String $upg_click_cost = String.valueOf(upg_click_cost);
        String $upg_click_level = String.valueOf(upg_click_level);
        String $upg_click_effect = String.valueOf(upg_click_effect);
        //if he's new it will make him level 1
        if (upg_click_level == 0){
            upg_click_level = 1;
            upg_click_effect = 1;
            upg_click_effect = upg_click_level * 1;
            upg_click_cost = upg_click_level * 2;
        }
        do_llars = do_llars + upg_click_effect;
        TextView dollars = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dollars);
        dollars.setText($do_llars);

    }

    public void upgradeBuy(){
    if (do_llars >= upg_click_cost){
        do_llars = do_llars - upg_click_cost;
        upg_click_level = upg_click_level + 1;


    }

    }

}
```